# Google AMP : `Method: ampUrls.batchGet` is throwing `NO_AMP_URL` even if the AMP is present

Tags: amp-html, google-apis-explorer

Sample webpage: https://www.bloombergquint.com/politics/jyotiraditya-scindia-meets-prime-minister-even-as-congress-says-he-remains-incommunicado

If you check the source code you can see that AMP is present. The source code and Google AMP Test also confirm the same.

**Source code:**

[image: source code]

**Google AMP Testing tool**

[image: google amp test]

But the PSI api call gives me this error:

```
{
  "urlErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "https://www.bloombergquint.com/politics/jyotiraditya-scindia-meets-prime-minister-even-as-congress-says-he-remains-incommunicado"
    }
  ]
}
```

Findings when debugging:

1. The service worker is deleting the `rel="amphtml"` snippet from the page source after JS is powered up. (Check the source code after page is loaded completely in view page source)
2. The `mainEntityofPage` structured data is set to the home page of the site (bloombergquint.com) instead of the story page. (bloombergquint.com/:story-slug)
3. `ThumbnailURL` is missing from structured data(SD) but in the preview is working fine with SD testing tool. (In preview the page is shown as AMP also.)
4. What are the parameters this API is checking. ([API docs](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/acceleratedmobilepageurl/rest/v1/ampUrls/batchGet))
5. If the API is a success, the PSI (pagespeed insights) will hopefully show the `AMP Url discovered` message?

**Edit**

If the source code has an absolute URL to the AMP page than a relative URL, it shows success. What's the recommended content for `rel="amphtml`?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested https://www.bloombergquint.com/politics/jyotiraditya-scindia-meets-prime-minister-even-as-congress-says-he-remains-incommunicado and it looks like everything is in order and the page appears in Google Search results as AMP.

However, there seems to be a problem with the AMP URL API, as it indeed does not return the AMP version of the page. This might be related to the link rel=amphtml being removed on load (which is something I would not recommend doing).

Comment: Oh, we fixed it. I'll add the findings as an answer.  I think it was mainly because the AMPUrl was relative, not absolute.